# How do I run a CompletableFuture handler on the Vertx event loop thread?

Tags: java, java-8, reactive-programming, vert.x, completable-future

I have a library xyz that gives me a CompletableFuture which I want to process on my Vertx (v3.5) event loop. Currently I am using [CompletableFuture.handle(BiFunction)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-) (see below) but I would like to use [CompletableFuture.handleAsync(BiFunction, Executor)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handleAsync-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.concurrent.Executor-), but I cannot figure out how to provide the vertx event loop thread to the second parameter in this method call.

I tried executing this whole code in [Vertx.runOnContext()](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vertx/vertx-core/3.5.1/io/vertx/core/Vertx.html#runOnContext-io.vertx.core.Handler-) but the calls inside handleAsync still executed on Java's ForkJoin pool which I want to avoid.

```
CompletableFuture<Void> f = xyz.someMethod();
f.handle((v, th) -> { //Want to run this in handleAsync()
   if (th == null) {
     future.complete(null);
   } else {
     future.completeExceptionally(th);
   }
   return null;
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this by simply using `vertx.nettyEventLoopGroup()` as the second parameter, so your code will be something like this:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> f = xyz.someMethod();
f.handleAsync((v, th) -> { 

  if (th == null) {
    future.complete(null);
  } else {
    future.completeExceptionally(th);
  }

  return null;
}, vertx.nettyEventLoopGroup());
```

**Note:** the above code will may run the callback code not on the same thread the Vertx future was running.

To preserve the threading model of the Vertx you need to use the following code:

```
CompletableFuture<String> f = xyz.someMethod();
Context context = vertx.getOrCreateContext();
f.handleAsync((v, th) -> {
    context.runOnContext(event -> {
        if (th == null) {
            future.complete(null);
        } else {
            future.completeExceptionally(th);
        }
    });
    return null;
});
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. I had no idea this existed.

Comment: Better make it handleAsync, because that is what we need and which takes 2 arguments.

Comment: I write this for the sake of correctness; you have written vertx.nettyEventLoopGroup() as a second argument of f.handle() which is not compilable as f.handle does not take two arguments. So please correct it to make it f.handleAsync().

Answer (score 0):

This can be done the following way. It is a workaround, not an optimal solution. Initially I placed the runOnContext call outside handle method, which is why it did not work.

`CompletableFuture<Void> f = xyz.someMethod();
f.handle((v, th) -> { 
   vertx.runOnContext(e->{
     if (th == null) {
       future.complete(null);
     } else {
       future.completeExceptionally(th);
     }
   });
  return null;
});`

This will make one extra context switch (from ForkJoin pool to vertx event loop) which is one disadvantage of this approach.